# Pass php's auto-incremented loop variable values to jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I'm trying to make some input boxes and use incremented variable in name property. After done looping, I make a `readonly` input box to display the value of the inputs.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?
$a=6;
for($I=1; $I < $a; $I++){
    echo "<input type='text' name='inp".$I."' value='' class='myInput'><br>";
}
echo "<input type='text' name='displayAverage' value='' readonly><br>";
?>
```

For the script, I made a function to Average the values in `inp".$I` boxes and display it in "displayAverage" box.

Here is the script for the function:

```js
<script>

var input = $('[name="<? echo "inp'".$I."'"; ?>"],[name="<? echo "inp'".$I."'"; ?>"],[name="<? echo "inp'".$I."'"; ?>"]'),
    input1 = $('[name="<? echo "inp'".$I."'"; ?>"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="<? echo "inp'".$I."'"; ?>"]'),
    input3 = $('[name="<? echo "inp'".$I."'"; ?>"]'),
 input4 = $('[name="displayAverage"]');
$('body').on('input', function () {
    var vArray = $('input.myInput').filter(function(i,el){
      return $(el).val().trim() != "";
    }).map((j,k) => +k.value).get();
    var res = vArray.reduce((a,c) => a+c,0)/vArray.length;
    input4.val(res);
});
</script>
```

It seems like the variables won't pass to the script. What am I missing? And how do I get it to work with the Average function?

Comment: To make clean, reusable code, you'd be much better off using an ajax call to get the values you need, then dynamically create the input boxes and populate them with the results.

Comment: Do you mean the <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: Well, jQuery is just one way to use ajax. But if you're not familiar with ajax, run through a few tutorials (there are tons to choose from) it will really make things clear for you. Because it's very messy to be injecting php directly in to your javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var input = $('[name="<?php echo "inp".$I.""; ?>"],[name="<?php  echo "inp".$I.""; ?>"],[name="<?php  echo "inp".$I.""; ?>"]'),
input1 = $('[name="<?php  echo "inp".$I.""; ?>"]'),
input2 = $('[name="<?php  echo "inp".$I.""; ?>"]'),
input3 = $('[name="<?php  echo "inp".$I.""; ?>"]'),
input4 = $('[name="displayAverage"]');
$('body').on('input', function () {
    var vArray = $('input.myInput').filter(function(i,el){
      return $(el).val().trim() != "";
    }).map((j,k) => +k.value).get();
    var res = vArray.reduce((a,c) => a+c,0)/vArray.length;
    input4.val(res);
});
```

Comment: It works, Sir! Could you point me to my mistakes, Sir? Maybe it's just my eyes cannot find the problem of my code.

Comment: you put single quotation in your variable [name="<?php echo "inp'".$I."'"; ?>"] which changed your input box name. So i removed the single quotation and it works. Please accept the answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: Sir. What if I make an increment in class='myInput' into--- class='myInput".$I."'?
What should I do to get the script worked? Because so far i've tried like----->

var vArray = $('input.<?php echo "myInput".$I.""; ?>').filter(function(i,el){

but it does not work. Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: as per my understanding to your current question you want to increment in class name. But when you do that then each input box will have unique class name. class is more like work as group. i think your should assign ID rather then unique class name.

Comment: I see it now, Sir. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I hope I didn't bother you with this question, Sir.

Comment: Sorry i can only mark this answer. I haven't been able to upvote due to my reputation as new user here.

Answer (score 0):

I say pass the value of `$I` in the `value` attribute of your input fields first.

Also, I did something different with your scripts. Here's the working code:

```
<?php
$a=6;
for($I=1; $I < $a; $I++){
echo "<input type='text' name='inp".$I."' value='$I' class='myInput'><br>";
}
echo "<input type='text' name='displayAverage' value='' readonly><br>";
?>
```

And for the jQuery:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total= 0;

    $('.myInput').each(function(){
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());

        total += value;
    });

    var total_elements = $('.myInput').length;

    var average = total/total_elements;

    $( "input[name='displayAverage']" ).val(average);
});    
</script>
```

We are looping through all input elements with class `.myInput` and we are getting their values. We then add that to a `total` variable. From there get the number of elements with class `myInput` and use that to find your average.

Comment: It works great, Sir. But what if I need the input values to be empty so I can input values manually and get the same result like in your code, Sir?

Comment: I would say then pass the $I value in some other attribute, and grab the value from it. Maybe the id attribute? Then change var value = parseInt($(this).val()); to var value = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));